# How to change the timezone setting with Spark Structured Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, timezone, spark-structured-streaming

I have something like this. How do I change the timezone in the `func` function?

```
def func(mb_df, batch_num):
# I need to set the timezone here How do I do the equivalent of ...
#   spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", MyTimeZone)?

df.writeStream \
  .format("delta") \
  .foreachBatch(func) \
  .outputMode("update") \
  .option("checkpointLocation", ...) \
  .start()
```

I tried  `mb_df._jdf.sparkSession().conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", MyTimeZone)`, but that gives me the error `AttributeError: 'JavaMember' object has no attribute 'set'`.

Comment: I don't think that possible. Both on Python and the JVM (which runs PySpark eventually) timezone is picked up from configuration / env settings at app startup and cannot be changed dynamically inside a function.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? do you want to change tz of the session or the tz of some column in your df?